# DIV Content Text appear in a single row / Line

Tags: javascript, css

```
div ><hr><p><span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Site:</span> Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Device:</span> CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Interface:</span> Wilmington DataCenter, DC  <span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Print</span><hr></p></div>
```

Hi , Inside a div Tag i am put up some text inside `<HR><P> here some content </p></HR>`

The content is put up with the help of  some span tags in between .

Currently the content is displayed in two lines .

I want to make all this content appear in a single row /Line

Please advice .

Comment: `hr` tags don't have content. They are self closing tags.

Comment: It appears to be in single row/line if you aren't missing the `<` in your opening div.

Comment: i see only one line: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/6jnTe/

Comment: i want to have as a Parallel line with some content in that , so the reason i have chosen this <HR> , could you please suggest an alternate way for this ??

Comment: I am opening the current window as a pop window using window.open(). so its coming in two lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
```

and you do have an error in your code the second `hr` should be outside the `<p>..</p>` `p` elements can only contain in flow text or inline elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><hr><p><span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Site:</span> Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Device:</span> CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Interface:</span> Wilmington DataCenter, DC  <span STYLE="font-size:24; color: black">Print</span><hr></p></div>
```